# American citizen travelling to London from Ghana - do I need a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, us-citizens

I am a naturalized American travelling to Ghana and UK. I know I need a visa for Ghana, but what do I need to show at the Ghana airport coming to UK?

Comment: you don't need to show anything to enter the UK as an American citizen

Comment: @Karlson If I understand the question correctly, this is not a dupe. My understanding of the question is asking whether a U.S. citizen needs a U.K. visa when entering the U.K. from a third country (specifically, Ghana,) while the other question is asking whether a transit visa is needed to fly through the U.K. en route to another country.

Comment: @reirab why would the country they are coming from make a difference?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier it wouldn't, but the person asking the question seems to be unaware of that, which is why that is the topic of the question.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier As far as I know, it normally wouldn't, which is presumably the correct answer. :)

Comment: phoog, reirab, fair enough.

Answer (score 7):

You can generally enter the UK with only your US passport, without a visa.  It does not matter what country you are traveling from.  The important factor is your citizenship.

For certain purposes, however, US citizens do require a visa to enter the UK, for example, for study or employment, so it's not possible to answer your question fully without knowing the reason for your trip.

The UK government has a calculator that takes such circumstances into account at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa.